# Scanner, useDelimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I encounter some problem when using useDelimiter from the Scanner class.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("-");
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

if I have this input

> A-B-C

the output will be

> A B

and wait until I type in another "-" for it to print out the last character

However if I instead of having user input data, and insert a String to the Scanner instead the code will work. What's the reason for it, and how do I fix it? I don't want to use StringTokenzier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `Scanner` didn't wait for you to enter another `-` then it would erroneously assume that you were done typing input.

What I mean is, the `Scanner` must wait for you to enter a `-` because it has no way to know the length of the next input.

So, if a user wanted to  type `A-B-CDE` and you stopped to take a sip of coffee at `C`, it woud not get the correct input. (You expect `[ A, B, CDE ]` but it would get `[ A, B, C ]`)

When you pass it in a full `String`, `Scanner` knows where the end of the input is, and doesn't need to wait for another delimiter.

How I would do it follows:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = stdin.nextLine();
String[] splitInput = input.split("-", -1);
```

You will now have an array of `Strings` that contain the data between all of the `-`s.

[Here is a link to the `String.split()` documentation for your reading pleasure.](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: so there's no way around this but to use one Scanner which takes the full input, and another Scanner which parse the input?

Comment: @klw, you only need 1 `Scanner`.

Comment: won't String.split add whitespace to the String array as well? I have vague memory using split before.

Comment: @klw, no.  If you have the string `"A-B-C-D".split("-")` you get the array `["A","B","C","D"]`

Answer (score 3):

You could use an alternative delimiter string `useDelimiter( "-|\n" );` 
It works with a String argument as well as by reading from `System.in`.
In case of System.in this requires you to press enter at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it follows:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = stdin.nextLine();
String[] splitInput = s.split("-", -1);
```

You will now have an array of `Strings` that contain the data between all of the `-`s.