# Java: Error with reading in file with delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, delimiter

I have a file with multiple fields that i need to store individually into an array.

```
Steve;stiffy;123;88
Sam;sammy;456;55
```

But when i try storing them i keep getting error saying java.util.NoSuchElementException

Here is my code for storing the data

```
void loadCustomer(){

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("CustomerInfo.txt"));
        sc.useDelimiter(";");
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            cusName.add(sc.next());
            cusUser.add(sc.next());
            cusPass.add(sc.next());
            cusCCNum.add(sc.next());
        }
}
```

I could get it to work by changing

```
cusCCNum.add(sc.next());
```

to

```
cusCCNum.add(sc.nextLine());
```

but it will ignore the delimiter and when i print out cusCCNum.get(1), it will display

```
;88
```

instead of

```
88
```

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the line number and stack trace for your error?  It might provide us some insight on where the problem lies.

Comment: Change your delimiter to `sc.useDelimiter("[;\\n]");`.

Comment: accepted answer on this question looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493230/scanner-usedelimiter

Comment: thanks guys for the input, using `sc.useDelimiter("[;\\n]");` and `scanner.useDelimiter(";|\n");` solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no delimiter between 88 and Sam..

```
  scanner.useDelimiter(";|\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use String tokenizer instead of delimiter. 
Get input as a string and parse it by ; character as token.

Learn, how to use stringtokenizer [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=236)

Answer (score 0):

You are causing the exception while you are calling the 4 next elements for each one check if there is 1 next element, this would do the following:

```
while (RecentElement is not the last one)
{
    Read (RecentElement + 1)
    Read (RecentElement + 2)
    Read (RecentElement + 3)
    Read (RecentElement + 4)
}
```

And somewhen you get the [exception of the next() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) because you access an element that is just not there:

> Throws: NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

You should use the new line as a delimiter and for each new line parse the data from the record, for example using the split function:

```
   sc.useDelimiter("\n");      
   while (sc.hasNext())
   {
       for(String g: sc.next().split(";"))
         System.out.println(g);          
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to read each line, token it using delimeter and set values to array.

I could do it via StringTokenizer.

```
while (sc.hasNextLine())            {               
                StringTokenizer st =  new StringTokenizer(sc.nextLine(),";");               
                while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                    System.out.println(st.nextElement());
                }
            }
```

I am surprised and need to read more on Scanner api to see why its not working with scanner.